# single signon using multiple domains for asp.net web app and share point

Tags: sharepoint, web-applications, single-sign-on, acs, multiple-domains

My requirement is to support my-webapp and a sharepoint site with single signon supporting multiple domain (not limited to a single domain).
As i am new to these any pointers could be helpful.
Probable looking for microsoft ACS or any other options open.
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Please show us what you have tried and the problems you are experiencing.

Comment: I have a webapp that supports custom authentication using database approach, i want to extend the weapp to support multiple domains with single signon support for sharepoint site also, as mentioned above

Comment: i have tried with azure AD but it supports for single domain support only as per my knowledge.